# Can't get upserted ids for bulk operation in mongodb + ubuntu?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, ubuntu

I am trying to get he upserted ids for a bulk operation with the ruby mongo driver. **It works when I try on my mac** but not when I am working on the linux, ubuntu server.

I installed mongo the regular way on both platforms (brew and apt-get) so maybe there is a difference in the configuration. Whatever it is, I dont know what I'm missing. I get the upserted_count on both, but only get upserted_ids on the Mac.

Here is the code I am calling:

```
bulk_data = []
bulk_data << {replace_one: {replacement: data, filter: e.matching_key, upsert: true}} # several times inside a loop
```

and later

```
bulk_write(bulk_data, ordered: false)
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Ok, problem solved. It turns out Ubuntu was on Mongo 2.4 and Mac on 3.0. Mongo 2.4 wont return upserted_ids. So make sure you update it to the newest version.

Here are the deb package sources: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/